# Django Rest Framework, many to many groups

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I'm new to using DRF. I have a 2 layered many-to-many relationship I would like to be able to serve up.

```
# models.py
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
class Group (models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    people = models.ManyToManyField(Person,related_name='groups',blank=True)
class Event(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    groups = models.ManyToManyField(Group,related_name='events',blank=True)
```

In my serializer I would like to be able to show in Person, which event they are attending.

```
class PersonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    groups = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True)
    #not sure how to lookup the events related field here...
    events = EventSerializer(source='groups.name', many=True,read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ('name', 'events')
```

However, I'm getting an error when I look up events. Is this lookup even possible?

Currently the output looks like this:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "mike",
    "groups": [
        "dev"
    ],
    "events": null
}
```

I'd would like the output to be a list of events.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this works or not,

```
class EventSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        Model = Event
        fields = ('name')

class GroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    events = EventSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Group
        fields = ('name', 'events')
```

Then, update PersonSerializer,

```
class PersonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    groups = GroupSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ('name', 'groups')
```

Comment: i get an error: AssertionError: It is redundant to specify `source='groups'` on field 'ListSerializer' in serializer 'MemberSerializer', because it is the same as the field name. Remove the `source` keyword argument.